# How to find a specific rows + n in SQL Server table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to create a SQL query that shows me messages with `text1` and `text3`. I do not want to show anything else. I can find `text1` and `text1` id+2, but because there are other messages from other sources I cannot use id. I would also rather have everything in same column instead of making 2 columns.

```
select 
    a.id,
    a.message as cur
    b.message as next
from 
    mytable as a
join 
    mytable as b on a.id = b.id - 2
where 
    a.message like '%text1%'
```

My table:

| id | source | message |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | a | text1 |
| 02 | a | text2 |
| 03 | a | text3 |
| 04 | a | text1 |
| 05 | b | herp |
| 06 | c | derp |
| 07 | a | text4 |
| 08 | a | text5 |
| 09 | b | derp |
| 10 | a | text1 |
| 11 | a | text6 |
| 12 | a | text7 |

Output should be like:

| message |
| --- |
| text1 |
| text3 |
| text1 |
| text5 |
| text1 |
| text7 |

or this is okay too, but I would prefer first one:

| message | message |
| --- | --- |
| text1 | text3 |
| text1 | text5 |
| text1 | text7 |

Comment: what is the logic ? why does text5 and text7 appear in your expected ?

Comment: Every time if you find text1 there always will be fixed n number of rows that contain other message texts that are related to text1. I want to search for instances of text1 and also find and include related message text + 2 rows from source a.

Comment: What I think I should do is add row numbers somehow in query, but I am not sure what is  clever way to do it.

Comment: And what if the row with id 02 would not exist, how must the expected result than look like ?

Comment: Ideally it would start looking from +2 row onwards until it will find first search string like <search string> but I am not sure how time consuming this would be. It does not matter if it will occassionally return wrong value. I have currently also another problem that sometimes +2 row is not what it is supposed to be, so I would need to continue search until I find next '<search string>'.

Comment: @JariYlilahti, then a `... JOIN cte b ON a.rn <= b.rn - 2` and the appropriate `WHERE` clause is also an option (to _... start looking from +2 row onwards until it will find first search string ..._). But, additional test data will help here.

Comment: @JariYlilahti Could you formalize the search criteria for <search string>?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done via `LEAD` analytic function as follows:

Query with a two-column result:

```
With CTE As (
Select [message], Lead([message], 2) Over (Order by id) As message_1
From Tbl
Where [source]='a' 
)
Select [message], message_1
From CTE
Where [message] Like '%text1%'
```

Result:

| message | message_1 |
| --- | --- |
| text1 | text3 |
| text1 | text5 |
| text1 | text7 |

Query with a single column result:

```
With CTE As (
Select [message], Lead([message], 2) Over (Order by id) As message_1
From Tbl
Where source='a' 
)
Select V.[message]
From CTE Cross Apply (VALUES([message]), (message_1)) As V([message])
Where CTE.[message] Like '%text1%'
```

Result:

| message |
| --- |
| text1 |
| text3 |
| text1 |
| text5 |
| text1 |
| text7 |

Comment: Should have `PARTITION BY source`, and the results should include the necessary columns to enforce ordering.

Comment: @MatBailie I supposed that other sources would be filtered out by the first table scan operator.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to understand the question, but based on the additional explanations in the comments (*... I want to search for instances of **text1** and also find and include related message text **+2 rows** from **source a** ...*), two possible approaches to get the expected results are `ROW_NUMBER()` and `LEAD()`. Note, that you need an additional `APPLY` operator with a `VALUES` table value constructor to unpivot the columns:

Table:

```
SELECT *
INTO MyTable
FROM (VALUES
  (01, 'a', 'text1'),
  (02, 'a', 'text2'),
  (03, 'a', 'text3'),
  (04, 'a', 'text1'),
  (05, 'b', 'herp'),
  (06, 'c', 'derp'),
  (07, 'a', 'text4'),
  (08, 'a', 'text5'),
  (09, 'b', 'derp'),
  (10, 'a', 'text1'),
  (11, 'a', 'text6'),
  (12, 'a', 'text7')
) v (id, source, message)
```

Statement with `ROW_NUMBER()` and a self-join:

```
; WITH cte AS (
   SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS rn
   FROM MyTable
   WHERE source = 'a'
)    
SELECT c.message
FROM cte a
JOIN cte b ON a.rn = b.rn - 2
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (1, a.message), (2, b.message)) c (rn, message)
WHERE a.message like '%text1%'
ORDER BY a.rn, c.rn
```

Statement with `LEAD()`:

```
; WITH cte AS (
   SELECT *, LEAD(message, 2) OVER (ORDER BY id) AS message2
   FROM MyTable
   WHERE source = 'a'  
)    
SELECT c.message
FROM cte a
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (1, a.message), (2, a.message2)) c (rn, message)
WHERE a.message LIKE '%text1%'
ORDER BY a.id, c.rn
```

Result:

```
message
-------
text1
text3
text1
text5
text1
text7
```